# Изменение цвета строк таблицы в JSP JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Есть JSP страница

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR" pageEncoding="EUC-KR" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
    <title>Meals</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>MealsWithExceed</h2>
<table border=1>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>dateTime</th>
        <th>description</th>
        <th>calories</th>
        <th>exceed</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <jsp:useBean id="MealsWithExceeded" scope="request" type="java.util.List"/>
    <c:forEach items="${MealsWithExceeded}" var="mealWE">
        <tr style="background-color:#{ (mealWE.exceed == true ? 'greenyellow' : 'red')}">
            <td>
                <fmt:parseDate value="${ mealWE.dateTime }" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm" var="parsedDateTime"
                               type="both"/>
                <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" value="${ parsedDateTime }"/>
            </td>
            <td><c:out value="${mealWE.description}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${mealWE.calories}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${mealWE.exceed}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p><a href="./">Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

пытаюсь поменять цвет строки таблицы в зависимости от значения поля `exceed` -

```
<tr style="background-color:#{ (mealWE.exceed == true ? 'greenyellow' : 'red')}">
```

подскажите, как правильно сделать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr style="background-color:${mealWE.exceed ? 'greenyellow' : 'red'}">
```

Comment: Отлично работает. Спасибо!